# How to fill multiple input fieds with one MySQL query

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I know how to fill a single INPUT field with an ajax call like this. Suppose this is GO.PHP:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = ".$_GET['param']." "); 
while($review = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    echo $review['description'];
}
```

When I click the following:

```
<a class="editlink" id="<?php echo $review['id']; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $review['title']; ?></a>
```

I call ajax like this:

```
$(".editlink").click(function() {
    $.get("go.php", {param: $(this).attr('id')}, 
        function(data) {
            $('textarea#area1').html(data);
        });    
    return false;
});
```

'data' is filled by 'echo $review["description"]' and passed to TEXTAREA which is populated correctly. Ok, up to now everything works. But I don't know how to populate two, three, four, etc fields with the same mySQL query. Suppose I also had:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="text" name="date">
<input type="text" name="author">
```

How do I have to pass 'data' (GO.PHP) to populate all the INPUT fields?

Comment: The same value, or different values from the same query?

Comment: Different values from the same query: title, date, description, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate and send a JSON string with GO.PHP.  The JSON string from GO.PHP would be something like:

```
 {"title" : "mytitle", "date" : "mydate", "author" : "myauthor"}
```

Then on the client side:

```
jsonOBJ = {};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "go.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     jsonOBJ = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     for (var key in jsonOBJ) {
       $("input[name=" + key + "]").val(jsonOBJ[key]);
     }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select mutiple elements in a range of different ways.

I´d recommend that you both wrap and add a class to the `input` elements you´d like to select. That way you´d be able to use a selector like this;

```
$('div#container-element input.customClass').html(data);
```

Other ways to select the elements;

**Mutiple elements by IDs**

```
$('#input1, #input2')
```

**All `input` elements within an element**

```
$('div#container-element input')
```

**All `input` elements of type "text"**

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

Read the jQuery documentation about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for information and inspiration :)

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question. I know how to use selectors. I don't know how to do the following relation: db_record_1 => input_filed_1; db_record_2 => input_field_2. Please read again my post. Thank you.